# How to save cronjob error to file and email it?

Tags: linux, cron

my goal is to **save** cronjob error **and email** it to me. I don't care about standard output, that's why I redirect it to /dev/null.

Sending mail is done by this setting in crontab:

```
MAILTO=my@email.com
```

I tried to run it with following command:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null 2 >> /path/to/file.log
```

It emails the error all right. The log file is created but is **empty**.

What am I doing wrong?

==================================================================================

**I found the solution. Thank you all for your help!** (I cannot post it as an answer, so I am amending the solution here.)

I used this reference [How can I redirect stderr to a pipe?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/047)

```
# version 2: redirect stderr to the pipe without getting stdout (it's
# redirected to /dev/null)
myprog 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep ...
```

**My solution is:**

```
#crontab    
MAILTO=my@email.com
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a /path/to/file.log
```

Explanation: redirecting stderr to the pipe without getting stdout and then using tee -a for appending the stderr to the log file and printing it to the terminal, which is redirected automatically to email (see MAILTO).

So I have a log file and email both containing the error message.

Comment: `crontab` needs the full path of the scripts to be executed. Try with `* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script.sh ...`

Comment: Does your script actually send anything to stderr?

Comment: @fedorqui it's not a problem of the path, the file is created all right

Comment: @MikeW yes, I get the error message in email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is:

```
#crontab    
MAILTO=my@email.com
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a /path/to/file.log
```

Explanation see above in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

try this , it works

```
* * * * * script.sh >/dev/null 2>> /path/to/file.log  || echo "error check log file"
```

Comment: Thank you. This good, but I found out the solution. Will post it lower.

Comment: Well, I am a newbie here so I cannot post an answer so soon, so I added it to my question.